# How do I combine ID, and Class together with an active?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a sidebar and when it is active, I want the wrapper to change its `margin-left` to 89px to make it responsive.

Is there a way to combine an ID, an active class, and the dashboard wrapper class together?
CSS

```
#sidebar.active .dashboard-wrapper {
   margin-left: 89px;
}
```

HTML placing

```
<div class="nav-left-sidebar sidebar-dark" id="sidebar">
    SIDEBAR CONTENTS
</div>

<div class="dashboard-wrapper">
    MAIN CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: That should work.. that says target something with the class "dashboard-wrapper" that is INSIDE (the space) something with the id "sidebar" AND the class "active"

Comment: It's now working for me. The entire wrapper isn't changing its margin-left when the sidebar button ID is active. :< Maybe there's something wrong with the placement.

Here's how it goes:
`<div class="nav-left-sidebar sidebar-dark" id="sidebar">
    SIDEBAR CONTENTS
</div>

<div class="dashboard-wrapper">
    MAIN CONTENT
</div>`

Is there a way to connect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.dashboard-wrapper` isn't a child of `#sidebar`, it's sibling. Use `+` selector.

```
#sidebar.active + .dashboard-wrapper {
   margin-left: 89px;
}
```

Or use your current styles and change HTML markup and put `.dashboard-wrapper` into `#sidebar`.

```
<div class="nav-left-sidebar sidebar-dark" id="sidebar">
    SIDEBAR CONTENTS

    <div class="dashboard-wrapper">
        MAIN CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!! THANK YOU!!!